# Converting JWT encoded string to JwtAuthenticationToken

Tags: java, spring-security, jwt

I have a string representing JWT token, eg.

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c
```

and I would like to transform it into an instance of `org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt` class or `JwtAuthenticationToken`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Did you check the documentation? I don't know Java but this looks like a likely candidate https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/jwt/Jwt.html#withTokenValue(java.lang.String)

Comment: It seems that you are trying to do it outside of the standard [OAuth2 resource server security filter-chain configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/index.html). Why? (I mean why would you need a `Jwt` or `JwtAuthenticationToken` in that case and not just a `Map<String, Object>` with token claims?)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Spring Security's `JwtDecoder` to decode the JWT token and create a `JwtAuthenticationToken instance.

Here is an Example:

```java
    import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
    import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
    import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtException;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtValidationException;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder;
    
    import java.util.Collections;
    
    public class JwtUtils {
    
        public static Authentication getAuthenticationFromJwtToken(String jwtToken) throws JwtException {
            JwtDecoder jwtDecoder = new NimbusJwtDecoder(); 
            Jwt jwt = jwtDecoder.decode(jwtToken);

            String username = jwt.getSubject();
            String[] authorities = jwt.getClaimAsStringArray("authorities");

            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    username,
                    null,
                    Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authorities[0]))
            );
        }
    }
```

Here are some resources you should read:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/jwt/JwtDecoder.html
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/authentication/JwtAuthenticationToken.html

Comment: Thanks, it helps a bit. Could you please provide the arguments for the NimbusJwtDecoder and their meaning as I'm strugling with this the most. Getting:

Comment: An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Signed JWT rejected: Another algorithm expected, or no matching key(s) found

Comment: This could help you: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/jwt/NimbusJwtDecoder.html